# I am trying to install kivy on my Mac book. But I get the error below

Tags: python, kivy, dependencies, kivy-language

ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
Failed to build kivy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

- Scroll down to kivy and download the wheel file for kivy.
- Download it in the directory of your project
- Then try to install the wheel file using `pip install` (Use tab-key to autocomplete the long name)